# How to sort div elements according to div id from a given list/array?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the sorting order in a variable.

```
   var sortorder = "Amazon,Soap,Drugstore,Walmart,Walgreens".split(',');
```

and my requirement is that it should be arranged in the above given order and if some div's id is not available in the array then it should be appended in the last. The code below is ordering data in the order but the problem is if the div id doesn't exist in the array then it's not moving that div to the last.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="wtb_results_online right_results wtb_results_online_results_vantage">
      <div class="results">
            <h3><span>Online Retailers</span></h3>
            <div class="result_item result_innerdv" id="axyz"><span class="year">axyz</span><a class="btn_pack_sizes" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
            <div class="result_item result_innerdv" id="Drugstore"><span     class="year">Drugstore</span><a class="btn_pack_sizes" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
            <div class="result_item result_innerdv" id="Walgreens"><span class="year">Walgreens</span><a class="btn_pack_sizes" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
            <div class="result_item result_innerdv" id="flipcart"><span     class="year">flipcart</span><a class="btn_pack_sizes" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
            <div class="result_item result_innerdv" id="Amazon"><span class="year">Amazon</span><a class="btn_pack_sizes" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
            <div class="result_item result_innerdv" id="Walmart"><span class="year">Walmart</span><a class="btn_pack_sizes" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  var sortorder = "Amazon,Soap,Drugstore,Walmart,Walgreens".split(',');

    $.each(function(index,value){
        $('.wtb_results_online_results_vantage .result').append($('.wtb_results_online_results_vantage .result'));

    });
    $('.wtb_results_online_results_vantage .results > div').each(function(){
        if($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), sortorder)==-1){
            $('.wtb_results_online_results_vantage .results').append($('.wtb_results_online_results_vantage .results'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: you are missing single quotes here `}).appendTo($('#container));`, correct it to `}).appendTo($('#container'));`

Comment: actly the code is working, what i want is the item which is not in the array list should comes at the last aftr soring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply try this

```
$.each(sortorder,function(index,value){
    if($.inArray(value, sortorder)!==-1){
        $('#container').append($('#'+value));
    }
});

$('#container div').each(function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), sortorder)==-1){
        // inArray will return -1, if the element was not found in array
        $('#container').append($('#'+$(this).attr('id')));
    }
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sgp69tv/3/)

Edit: Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sgp69tv/4/)

Comment: but those which are not present in sortorder are coming to the top and not to the last. see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1sgp69tv/1/)

Comment: actly the code is working, what i want is the item which is not in the array list should comes at the last aftr soring.i have checked thsi in fiddle bt if u add any div which id is not thr in the array den its not showing the result

Comment: i can see its working let me ckh in my real time code..thanks a lot.:)

Comment: @ling.s, now it is working as expected by OP. Thanks :)